# Invalid SQL statement with Recordset.Open

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset

I am getting a runtime error:

> -2147217900 "Invalid SQL statement" on this line of my code:

```vb
Call objRecordset.Open("frmTotalInventory", , , adLockBatchOptimistic)
```

I have this same code working in another MS Access project and the only difference is the form that it is referencing which is "frmTotalInventory".

I checked and the library references match between the two Access projects and I am not sure at all why I would be getting an SQL statement error. The other Access project has "InventoryForm" as the form referenced for the `Recordset.Open` if that helps. Full code listed below. If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Is frm a reserved word?

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandlerCall

GoTo ProgramStart 'Skip over error handling until needed

                                            '******************
ErrorHandlerCall:                           '**ERROR HANDLING**
Call Error.ErrorHandler(ByVal workbook)     '******************
                                                

ProgramStart:

'Open file dialog opens and returns the selected filepath from OpenFile module
Call OpenFileDialog(FilePath)
    
'Reset progress bar and progress label to 0
'so each time you import the values will reset
PB1 = 0
ProgressPercent.Caption = 0 & "%"
   
Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=(FilePath))
    
'This is needed to add records with VBA
Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
objRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

Call objRecordset.Open("frmTotalInventory", , , adLockBatchOptimistic)
    
'Loop runs within the LastRowFinder module to determine
'the last row used in the formatted workbook

Call GetLastRow(ByVal workbook, LastRowUsed)
    
'Math - This has to be after the "Call GetLastRow" in order for it to return
'the LastRowUsed variable that is used for calculating progress
Dim PbIncrement As Variant
PbIncrement = 1 / LastRowUsed
PbIncrement = Round(PbIncrement, 6) * 100
    
Call AddRecordsLoop(ByVal objRecordset, ByVal workbook, LastRowUsed, PbIncrement)
    
'Ensures progress bar is at 100% after adding all records
PB1 = 100
ProgressPercent.Caption = Round(PB1, 0) & "%"

'Close Excel Process
If Not (ExcelApp Is Nothing) Then ExcelApp.Quit


End Sub
```

Comment: I see no SQL above. Show us the problem SQL as well.

Comment: So you have a table or query named *frmTotalInventory*? If so, please show us the SQL definition. Please note forms cannot be used in `DAO.Recordeset.OpenRecordset`.

Comment: `frm` is not a keyword but `Error` is - you might want to change it to avoid potential issues.

Answer (score 1):

Well I could not feel more stupid. This entire time I did not realize I was referencing the form instead of a table.. the names had me confused between my two projects as the one I am working on was not created by me. Thank you for making me realize how dumb someone can actually be.

The solution was to change "frmTotalInventory" to "tblInventoryList" which is the name of the actual ***TABLE*** I was trying to reference.